# Changing textfield between enabled and disabled

Tags: java, wicket-1.5

I have 2 radio buttons and 1 TextField and now I want to do changing between enabled and disabled TextField. If radioFindText is selected then TextField must be enabled otherwise it must be disabled. I was trying with such code but it doesn't work and I am running out of possible solutions. It seems that method onSelectionChanged is never called, why?

EDIT
Ok I finally found a solution and maybe it is obvious for ppl who work in wicket for a while but for my first project I found it difficult to solve it. Here is the working code.

```
    searchedText.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    RadioGroup group = new RadioGroup("group", selected);
    group.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    Radio radioErrors = new Radio("errors", new Model<String>("ERRORS"));
    Radio radioFindText = new Radio("text", new Model<String>("Find text"));
    group.add(radioFindText.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onchange") {
        @Override
        protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget art) {
            searchedText.setEnabled(true);
            art.add(searchedText);
        }
    }));
    group.add(radioErrors.add(new AjaxEventBehavior(("onchange")) {
        @Override
        protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget art) {
            searchedText.setEnabled(false);
            art.add(searchedText);
        }
    }));
    group.add(searchedText);
    form.add(group);
```

Answer (score 0):

its been a long time, since i coded wicket, but maybe you could use this:

radioGroup.add(new AjaxFormSubmitBehavior("onchange") {public void
onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {...}}

i guess you need this to get "onchange" - notifications

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't want to submit from and then change TextField but I want to do that immediately so when this radio button is selected then text field is automatically enabled.

Comment: did you try it? i would actually expect that you would get this notification immediately after user change the value... Other thing would be, what do you actually get on this: "group.add(new AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(1)));"? i mean you should get some kind of notification from it?

Comment: Yes I tried it and nothing happened. I was using this selfupdating because I thought that it would refresh and update the choice in radios.

Comment: i found this one:http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/ajax-behavior-sample-with-radiogroup-radio-td1867440.html its the same problem you have. he managed to solve it

Comment: Well I found that earlier and already tried it but it still doesn't work for me. It seems like I am missing something all the time but I cannot find what it can be. I've tried all possible solutions from this link which you pasted here and ... nothing. Maybe it is because that topic is from 2008 so probably some things changed.

Comment: sorry, but i cant help you, had some tough time with wicket about 1 year ago:)